# Get IP address in Unity 3d using C#

Tags: c#, html, json, ip, unity-game-engine

I want to get all details of client ip like location, lattitude, state, city, country, speed, isp etc. like what this guys are doing

http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/

I want to get a response ideally in Json or XMl so that I don't have to parse HTML. Currently I'm parsing html

```
myIP = myExtIPWWW.text;
myIP=myIP.Substring(myIP.IndexOf("Your IP address is:"),myIP.IndexOf("</h3>"));
myIP=myIP.Substring(myIP.IndexOf(":")+1);
myIP=myIP.Substring(0,myIP.IndexOf("<"));
```

But I dont like this method. Is there any better way such that I could get response in Json and access all fields straight away?

Thanks

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are free databases that provide this information to you in a (large) flat-file or database format. One such example is the [MaxMind GeoLite Country / City Databases](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country).

You should know however that **not a single one of those details is accurate** (apart from *maybe* country). If you're trying to rely on them for anything  then you should possibly reconsider your strategy, an IP cannot be reliably "gelocated" and these databases generally work based on RIPE IP assignment of IPs to individual ISPs and their local offices and/or exchanges where they are based. At best, you would be working off the closest exchange to your user.

Of course, this doesn't apply if the user actually owns their own ISP/IP as they can give those details as anything to RIPE and that is what will be in your database.

---

Just to give an example of how these details can be *so wrong*, the site you referenced above gives me these details:

```
My IP address state:     London, City of
My IP address city:  London
My IP address latitude:  51.5142
My IP address longitude:     -0.0931
My ISP [?]:  VAIONI Group Ltd
```

I am in Manchester, and VAIONI is a reseller / connectivity endpoint, not my ADSL provider.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. What do think would be the best way?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do? But the "best way" is to not do it at all, it's simply not possible unless you're only trying to get the country, in which case you could rely on them with a 95% (made up, but seemingly workable!) accuracy.

Comment: Actually, that's a bit of a lie. Windows itself now provides a Geolocation API (much like browsers, mobile devices, etc) which will work off a number of factors such as GPS towers, IP, etc etc. Of course, this is still not 100% accurate in any way. My browser's GeoLocation for me puts me in Salford, I'm 25 miles away from there. (Assuming you use Windows of course, if a mobile device you could use it's Geolocation, they generally have GPS in which case it would be accurate!)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all details of client [..] like location, lattitude, state, city, country, speed, [..] etc

Then don't use the IP address (because I might've missed out on late updates, but AFAIK IP addresses don't contain a speed part), but the appropriate [function](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9GUXnhhsB50J%3aunity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates.html+&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl) for that:

```
  iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates();
  print("Location: " + iPhoneInput.lastLocation.latitude + " " + 
                       iPhoneInput.lastLocation.longitude + " " + 
                       iPhoneInput.lastLocation.altitude + " " + 
                       iPhoneInput.lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy + " " + 
                       iPhoneInput.lastLocation.timestamp);
```